# How to do a bitwise NOR Gate in Python (editing python maths to work for me)

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Say I was to write this:

```
a=01100001 
b=01100010 
c=01100011 
d=01100100 
e=01100101
```

each letter resembles the given numbers now how would I deal with the resembling values:

Python would want to do this:

```
a + b = 2200011
```

but what I want it to do is this

- if 0 and 0 are attempted to be added together show 1
- if 1 and 0 are attempted to be added together show 0
- if 0 and 1 are attempted to be added together show 0
- if 1 and 1 are attempted to be added together show 0

What I wish to do is `a + b = 10011100`

Is there a way to edit the way python works out maths in this instance?

do far i have given set values to represent the letters but i want to do is change the way that python gives me results to match XOR gate in the explanation above

so could anyone give example of a code to give set values (1+1=0)(0+0=1) ... e.g

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far...

Comment: You'd have to enter the values as strings instead and process the values character by character. What have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: so could anyone give example of a code to give set values (1+1=0)(0+0=1) ... e.g

Comment: Are you supposed to input and output binary representations? Because you can enter integers in binary notation but they'll then be treated as regular integers. E.g. `0b1010` is stored `10`, decimal. You can then format the integer again when printing.

Comment: And perhaps https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators and https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation are of interest.

Comment: And the operation you are attempting is *not* an XOR gate, it is a [NOR gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_gate) instead. An [XOR gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate) would give 1 if the inputs differ, 0 if they are equal.

Comment: it is allot more simple in my head normally if A represents 1 and B represents 1 python WILL give me 2 but what i want is the NOR gate giving out 0

Comment: all i want to know is can you change the maths python gives and if so how

Comment: This is **not** algebra. You are using bitwise binary logic, which Python supports just fine too. You just need to learn about that first, see the links.

Comment: I have +1 the question because I don't think it deserves the current -4. Ok OP is a noob and his question could have been better. But it's not that bad. The question remains interesting.

Answer (score 12):

You said:

> What I wish to do is a + b = 10011100

**My solution:**

```
>>> a=0b01100001
>>> b=0b01100010

>>> bin((a | b) ^ 0b11111111)
'0b10011100'
```

**And now, for the explanation:**

You are asking for a NOR bitwise operation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_gate if it's not obvious):

```
r = not (a or b)
```

Also, you can use De Morgan's law, that says that it's equivalent to:

```
r = (not a) and (not b)
```

In Python:

```
>>> bin((a ^ 0b11111111) & (b ^ 0b11111111))
'0b10011100'
```

You may also wonder what's that `^ 0b11111111`. Well, `not a` is equivalent to `a xor 1` and `xor` is written `^` in python. I'd suggest you write down the logic table if you are not 100% convinced. So basically, `^ 0b11111111` changes the 0 to 1 and the 1 to 0.

The `bin` function gives the binary representation of the number given as a parameter. The `0b` at the beginning of a number means that the number is given in base 2 (otherwise it's base 10).

**Edit:**

Initially, my first thought for this problem was:

```
bin(~(a|b))
```

But the result is `'-0b1100100'`. This is because in Python the number are signed. But it is also possible to get the good result by only keeping the first byte:

```
>>> bin(~(a|b) & 0xff)
'0b10011100'
```

**Edit 2:**

I've just found that OP asked another question in order to better understand my answer. So, if you wonder why I used a XOR to do the NOT, see a good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19203069/1787973

Comment: I'd like to have an explanation for the downvote so I can improve my answer.

Comment: No idea (perhaps because you didn't explain your xor trick in detail?) - Have a well-deserved upvote :)

Comment: ok so a=0b01100001  b=-0b1100010  i understand the binary but whats the 0b at the start as for the bin((a | b) ^ 0b11111111) im lost :(

Comment: i would appreciate if i could have a chat with people on a instant messaging service later on for me to get a better understanding of this, is this possible

Comment: or please email me pythonhelp101jhon@hotmail.com

Comment: @user2849377 please read my last lines I have just added. Hope that will help.

Comment: right im sorry for this but i am getting there (slowly) bin displays the binary as the result (clear) and ((a ^ 0b1111111) is (a (01100001) through  "XOR gate" then through "and gate" with the same process as "a" but with "b" right??

Comment: You could use `~` instead of `^ 0b11111111`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman That's what I've tried first but: `>>> a = 0b01010101
>>> bin(~a)
'-0b1010110'`

Answer (score 1):

You gave us the "truth table" of all possible inputs (thanks for that).  And you say that the output should be 1 if both inputs are 0, otherwise the output should be 0.  The name of that logical operation is NOR, i.e. the negation of OR.

Note that your inputs are base 10 numbers, but they appear to represent base 2 numbers, or bitsets.  So perhaps the first thing we should do is convert them from their base 10 form to base 2.  A simple (but not overly efficient) way would be `int(str(a), 2)`.

From there, it's just a matter of doing the NOR operation on the numbers.  From here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators it looks like you can do `~(x|y)` (negated OR, bitwise).

Comment: this is clearly way above me. Your making a string converting base 10 to 2 i get that but the !(x|y) im not quite sure what this is doing

Comment: +1 for your answer. "!" does not work as you expect but otherwise, I think it may help him to solve and understand his problem.

Comment: @Maxime: oh, I meant ~ but typo's the adjacent (and much more common) !.  Lame, and corrected above.

Comment: Yes but it does not work either: >>> bin(~(a | b))
'-0b1100100' that's why I used a xor in my solution.