# How to make a bitwise NOR gate

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand the code from [an answer I received earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19197816/68587):

```
a=0b01100001
b=0b01100010

bin((a ^ 0b11111111) & (b ^ 0b11111111))
```

This is my understanding:

- `bin` means that the result will be in binary form.
- `a` is the processes going through the gate
- `0b` means base 2 form

Could someone explain the rest? I am confused about `11111111`. `&` is the **and** gate (confused why this separates the two). And how would you change this to work for any other gate, e.g. XOR, NAND, or...?

Comment: Please add the code example including the name assignments for a and b.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197495/how-to-do-a-bitwise-nor-gate-in-python-editing-python-maths-to-work-for-me **original posing if it will help**

Comment: I have edited my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19197816/1787973) in order to add this solution: `bin(~(a|b) & 0xff)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a ^ 0b11111111      #exclusive or's each bit in a with 1, inverting each bit

>>> a=0b01100001
>>> bin(a ^ 0b11111111)
'0b10011110' 

>>> bin((a ^ 0b11111111) & (b ^ 0b11111111))
'0b10011100'
```

This is different than using the ~ operator since ~ returns a negative binary result.

```
>>> bin(~a & ~b)
'-0b1100100
```

The reason is the ~ operator inverts all bits used in representing the number, including the leading 0's that are not typically displayed, resulting in a 2's complement negative result.  By using ^ and the 8 bit binary mask, only the first 8 bits are inverted.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, I have updated my answer in order to link to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19197816/1787973

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the original answer, which explains how a NOR gate can be implemented using AND and NOT:

> You are asking for a NOR bitwise operation:
>
> ```
> r = not (a or b)
> ```
>
> Also, you can use De Morgan's law, that says that it's equivalent to:
>
> ```
> r = (not a) and (not b)
> ```

The poster than translates that pseudo-code into the Python you posted. For some reason he used `^ 0b11111111` to do a binary NOT, rather than simply `~`, which is what I would have chosen. If we switch `(a ^ 0b11111111)` to the simpler `~` then we get:

```
bin(~a & ~b)
```

That expression is how you write "(not a) and (not b)" in Python. `~` means NOT and `&` means AND.

A binary NOT flips all of the bits in a number. 0 becomes 1 and 1 becomes 0. The direct way to do that is with `~`. An indirect way to flip all the bits in a number is to XOR it with all 1 bits. That has the same effect, it's just longer to write.

Or actually, to be more precise, it has *almost* the same effect. `^ 0b11111111` flips the first eight bits of the number because there are eight 1's. Whereas `~` flips *all* of the bits. If you're interested in only the first 8 bits then you can add `& 0b11111111`, which truncates the results to 8 bits:

```
>>> bin((~a & ~b) & 0b11111111)
'0b10011100'
```

In my opinion this is better than the mysterious `^ 0b11111111`.

Comment: Not quite. `bin(~a&~b)` results in `'-0b1100100'`, whereas `bin((a ^ 0b11111111) & (b ^ 0b11111111))` gives the result `'0b10011100'` which is what the OP expected/desired.

Answer (score 0):

The `^` is the XOR operator.  XOR means Exclusive OR.  One of the operand to `^` is a sequence of ones.  This essentially means every bit in the other operand (viz., either `a` or `b`) will be **flipped**.  Once the two individual XOR operations are done, their results are OR-ed.

Looking outside of bits, and bitwise operations, if you see it from the realm of logic operations, the code is in essence doing `(! A ) ^ (! B)` which per DeMorgan's law is identically the same as `! (A v B)` which is the NOR operation.