# bitwise NOR Gate - what does & mean?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, nor

I'm trying to understand the code from an answer I received yesterday:

2nd: [How to make a bitwise NOR gate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19202865/731947)
1st: [How to do a bitwise NOR Gate in Python (editing python maths to work for me)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197495/how-to-do-a-bitwise-nor-gate-in-python-editing-python-maths-to-work-for-me)

```
a=0b01100001
b=0b01100010

bin((a ^ 0b11111111) & (b ^ 0b11111111))
```

I now understand EVERYTHING except:

the `&` between the two values

and the `^ 11111111`  ( I know that `0b` is base `2`)

Can someone please explain these?

Comment: Please include a link to the previous question, so everyone else doesn't have to go looking for it.

Comment: Better yet - include the code in this question.

Comment: It's already explained http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197495/how-to-do-a-bitwise-nor-gate-in-python-editing-python-maths-to-work-for-me

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations

Comment: Instead of posting a new question every time, please add a comment to explain what is unclear so I can improve my answer. Now, we have 3 questions for the same thing, it's a mess.

Answer (score 1):

**How `NOR` works?**

The expression `x NOR y` can be broken using `AND`, `OR`, and `NOT`:

```
x NOR y == NOT(x OR y) == NOT(x) AND NOT(y)
```

So, for your given values:

```
a=0b01100001
b=0b01100010
```

`a NOR b` would be `NOT(a) AND NOT(b)`. Now think how would you do a `NOT(a)`? You just need to flip the bits. What is the way to flip the bits? An `XOR(^)`. How?

```
0 ^ 1 == 1
1 ^ 1 == 0
```

So, taking the `XOR` of any bit with `1` will flip that bit. i.e. `NOT(somebit) == a XOR somebit`. So, in your case, just take an `XOR` of each bits in `a` and `b` with `1` will get you the `NOT`:

```
   01100001
^  11111111
------------
   10011110
```

That is, we do an `XOR` with `11111111`. Note the number of `1's` is same as the number of bits in `a`.

**Putting it together:**

```
NOT(a) = a ^ 0b11111111
NOT(b) = b ^ 0b11111111
```

Now, that we got the `NOT`s of `a` and `b`, let's do an `AND`. So, what's the way to do an `AND`? Just do a bitwise `&`.

That's pretty simple:

```
NOT(a) AND NOT(b) == (a ^ 0b11111111) & (b ^ 0b11111111)
```