# can this work with other bit wise gates?

Tags: python

I have been working on this bit of bit wise gates.

```
a=0b01100001
b=0b01100010

bin((a ^ 0b11111111) & (b ^ 0b11111111))

>>>0b10011100
```

So I was wondering how would you adjust this to work for nand gate and any other for that instance.

```
>>> bin((a ~ 0b11111111)& (b ~ 0b11111111))
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> bin((a ^ 0b11111111) ~ (b ^ 0b11111111))
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

does not work for example.

Comment: There is no NAND bitoperation according to [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

`~` is just negation.

You could use `~(a AND b)` in Your case.

Comment: @Kamiccolo, `~(a & b)` - `&` is bitwise, `AND` isn't Python, `and` is a short-circuiting boolean control structure ;-)

Comment: so **bin(a AND b)** if values are given surely not??

Comment: @TimPeters Peters, sorry, that's what I meant :) `~(a & b)`

Comment: bin((a=0b11111111) & (b=0b11111111)

Comment: @user2849377, no, again:  `AND` is not Python; `and` is incorrect in this context; `&` is Python's binary "and" operator, as you already know.

Comment: @user2849377, I have no idea what you mean by `bin((a 0b11111111) & (b 0b11111111)` - and neither does Python.  `a 0b11111111` all on its own is not Python syntax.

Comment: so what would you change from **bin((a ^ 0b11111111) & (a ^ 0b11111111))** to make it work for other gates

Comment: @user2849377:  please read the answer Erik Allik just gave you.  You have to learn Python's syntax first.  Then everything is easy :-)

Comment: In your first question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197495/how-to-do-a-bitwise-nor-gate-in-python-editing-python-maths-to-work-for-me) many users already gave you relevant websites in the comments. Please study a bit before posting. Quoting one of the comment: "And perhaps wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators and wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation are of interest."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start from here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

- `x << y`
  Returns x with the bits shifted to the left by y places (and new bits on the right-hand-side are zeros). This is the same as multiplying x by 2**y.
- `x >> y`
  Returns x with the bits shifted to the right by y places. This is the same as //'ing x by 2**y.
- `x & y`
  Does a "bitwise and". Each bit of the output is 1 if the corresponding bit of x AND of y is 1, otherwise it's 0.
- `x | y`
  Does a "bitwise or". Each bit of the output is 0 if the corresponding bit of x AND of y is 0, otherwise it's 1.
- `~ x`
  Returns the complement of x - the number you get by switching each 1 for a 0 and each 0 for a 1. This is the same as -x - 1.
- `x ^ y`
  Does a "bitwise exclusive or". Each bit of the output is the same as the corresponding bit in x if that bit in y is 0, and it's the complement of the bit in x if that bit in y is 1.

According to Wikipedia:

> The function NAND(a1, a2, ..., an) is logically equivalent to NOT(a1 AND a2 AND ... AND an).

So in order to make a bitwise NAND operation over operands `a` and `b` in Python:

```
~(a & b)
```

which you can put into a function:

```
bnand = lambda a, b: ~(a & b)
```

The corresponding non-bitwise NAND would be:

```
not (a and b)
```

so make sure you don't confuse `and` and `&` (as well as `not` and `~`); also, the logic operators are lower case.

**P.S.** Also, make sure you read this: [Python: unsigned 32 bit bitwise arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210629/python-unsigned-32-bit-bitwise-arithmetic)

Comment: can you explain (a ^ 0b11111111)

Comment: Explain what exactly in addition to what's in the doc?

Comment: @ErikAllik he wants you to explain what someone already explained to him: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202865/how-to-make-a-bitwise-nor-gate/19203069#19203069