# Understanding NOR operation

Tags: binary, bitwise-operators

I am wondering the logic behind NOR operation. Suppose we want to NOR the inputs 1, 1 (decimal base)

This is equivalent to 1, which is still 1 in a binary base so the NOR operation should be 0 by the truth table.

However, in Python, writing:

```
~(1 | 1)
```

yields `-2` as the result, not `0`. Is this something to do with signed numbers? Does it still apply even though the inputs are decimal base, not twos complement or unsigned binary?

Comment: Look at this question in the answers someone explains why you get that weird behaviour: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197495/how-to-do-a-bitwise-nor-gate-in-python-editing-python-maths-to-work-for-me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, integers are represented as 2s-complement (arbitraily large) bit strings.  So the number `1` is actually the bit string ...0000001  -- the least significant bit is 1 and all the rest are 0s.  When you do bitwise ops (such as | or ~) they operate on all the bits in parallel.  So ~(1 | 1) is:

```
    ...00000001
    ...00000001
 or -----------
    ...00000001
not -----------
    ...11111110
```

That final value (lowest bit 0, all the rest 1s) is the twos-complement representation of -2, so that is what gets printed.

If you want a single bit of output (eg. a 0 or 1), you can apply an `& 1` to the (full) expression to effectively extract (just) the least significant bit:

```
 >>> (~(1 | 1)) & 1
 0
```